# How do i enable code lens support for python in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am trying to find code lens support for python in visual studio code.
I am having many methods which are not used. Using 'find all references' for each method is time consuming and tedious.
If code lens facility there and show number of references for each method, it would be easier to clean up unused methods.

Can code lens be enabled for python in vscode ?
Sample code lens is given below

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the team doesn't want to move forward with this idea.

Some people have put forward this feature request, but the team thought there isn't an enough widespread need for this to warrant the maintenance cost for the feature.

You can refer to [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/115) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14788) to check the discussions of this feature request talking in the early.

While the `JavaScript`, `TypeScript` and `C#` extension has this feature. As you can enable it with:

```
"javascript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
"typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
"csharp.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true
```